# Use CSS to style element if background inline styling

Tags: html, css

consider following HTML and CSS:

I have the second element background set to red with inline styling. How can I style the element with the background:red? I know I can do :nth-child(2), but it is dynamicly different each time?

```
<div class="titleBox">
    <button>Click meh!</button>
</div>
<div class="titleBox" style="background:red">
    <button>Click meh!</button>
</div>
<div class="titleBox">
    <button>Click meh!</button>
</div>

.titleBox {
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
    float:left;
    border:1px solid;
    opacity:.5
}
```

So.. if style="background:red", make the opacity equal 1

thanks! http://jsfiddle.net/kM27C/

Comment: Use the attribute selector? `.titleBox[style*="background"]`.. http://jsfiddle.net/Yd4zw/

Comment: You'd be better off trying to check via JavaScript.

Comment: Javascript is hardly ever better if it can be done through plain CSS.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Just check whether the attribute exists**

Doesn't work properly in IE, but it does if you just check for the existence of the style attribute:

```
.titleBox[style] {
```

**Exact matching attribute selector**

Use the attribute selector:

```
.titleBox[style="background:red"] {
```

Demo-fiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/Empgz/) works fine for Chrome, but not for IE. Apparently IE parsed the style, adds some formatting, and then requires the selector to follow that formatting. I inspected the element, saw `style="background: red;"` (with space and semi-colon), so I tried this, which works in IE:

```
.titleBox[style="background: red;"] {
```

So, you could add both to your CSS, so it matches any:

```
.titleBox[style="background:red"],
.titleBox[style="background: red;"] /* For IE */ {
  /* properties go here */
}
```

It's dirty, of course, but if you cannot change the HTML, you'll sometimes have to do something like this. If you *can* change your HTML, remove the inline style and change it for a class.

**More special attribute selector (*starting with* or *contains*)**

There is also the `^=` operator, using which you can check whether an attribute *starts with* a value:

```
/* Any background setting */
.titleBox[style^=background] {
    opacity:1;
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/g7SZ5/1/

See also [The Skinny on CSS Attribute Selectors](http://css-tricks.com/attribute-selectors/) on CSS-tricks.com for more of such operators.

Comment: I cant get this to work how I want it.. http://jsfiddle.net/g7SZ5/ i need all 3 to have opacity 1 since they have background colors